# SQL: City where each product has been sold the most, close but not complete

Tags: sql-server

I have to find the city where each product sold best.
I feel I am pretty close but am stumped on what to try next. I've been working on this assignment for about 8 hours now (not even an exaggeration).

There are these tables:

```
Tb_Product (prod_id, name, MU)
Tb_Supplier (supp_id, name, city)
Tb_Consumer (con_id, name, city)
Tb_Requests (quantity, prod_id, price, con_id)
Tb_Offers (quantity, prod_id, price, supp_id)
Tb_Transactions (quantity, price, prod_id, supp_id, con_id, tran_id)
```

I have the following so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Tb_Product.Name, Tb_Supplier.City, SUM(Quantity) AS 'Quantity Sold'
FROM Tb_Supplier, Tb_Transactions, Tb_Consumer, Tb_Product
WHERE Tb_Supplier.Supp_ID = Tb_Transactions.Supp_ID
AND Tb_Product.Prod_ID = Tb_Transactions.Prod_ID
GROUP BY Tb_Product.Name, Tb_Supplier.Supp_ID, Quantity, Tb_supplier.City
HAVING SUM(Quantity) >= ALL(SELECT SUM(Quantity)
                        FROM Tb_Supplier, Tb_Transactions
                        WHERE Tb_Transactions.Supp_ID=Tb_Supplier.Supp_ID
                        GROUP BY Quantity)
```

and the output I get is like this:

```
Name                           City                           Quantity Sold
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ----------------------
Airplane                       Madison                        3900000
Auto                           Madison                        3900000
Computer                       Madison                        3900000
Milk                           Madison                        3900000
Oil                            Madison                        3900000
Orange                         Madison                        3900000
Truck                          Madison                        3900000
TV                             Madison                        3900000
```

Clearly the quantity sold isn't correct and I believe it has to do with the SUM(Quantity) up top but just can't figure out what to change.

Comment: You have four tables involved in the query, but I see only two join conditions.  Can you include the table definitions?

Comment: Supplier - supp_id, name, city
Consumer - con_id, name, city
Product - prod_id, name, MU
Requests - quantity, prod_id, price, con_id
Offers - quantity, prod_id, price, supp_id
Transactions - quantity, price, prod_id, supp_id, con_id, tran_id

Answer (score 0):

In this case `JOIN` is very useful than `WHERE`

```
SELECT p.Name, s.City, SUM(t.Quantity) AS 'Quantity Sold'
FROM Tb_Supplier s
JOIN Tb_Transactions t ON t.Supp_ID = s.Supp_ID
JOIN Tb_Consumer c ON c.con_id = t.con_id -- I think you forgot this condition
JOIN Tb_Product p ON p.Prod_ID = t.Prod_ID
GROUP BY p.Name, s.Supp_ID, s.City
HAVING SUM(t.Quantity) >= ALL(
            SELECT SUM(Quantity)
            FROM Tb_Transactions
            GROUP BY Supp_ID,prod_id -- check it
          )
```

And I think that `Quantity` isn't necessary in `GROUP BY`

```
GROUP BY Tb_Product.Name, Tb_Supplier.Supp_ID, /*Quantity,*/ Tb_supplier.City
```

Try the following query

```
SELECT
  p.name,
  d.city,
  d.QSold
FROM
  (
    SELECT t.prod_id,s.city,SUM(t.Quantity) QSold
    FROM Tb_Transactions t
    JOIN Tb_Supplier s ON s.supp_id=t.supp_id
    GROUP BY t.prod_id,s.city
  ) d
JOIN
  (
    SELECT prod_id,MAX(QSold) MaxQSold
    FROM
      (
        SELECT t.prod_id,s.city,SUM(t.Quantity) QSold
        FROM Tb_Transactions t
        JOIN Tb_Supplier s ON s.supp_id=t.supp_id
        GROUP BY t.prod_id,s.city
      ) d
    GROUP BY prod_id
  ) m
ON d.prod_id=m.prod_id AND d.QSold=m.MaxQSold
JOIN Tb_Product p ON d.prod_id=p.prod_id
```

Or this query if your version of SQLServer supports window-functions

```
SELECT name,city,QSold
FROM
  (
    SELECT t.prod_id,p.name,s.city,SUM(t.Quantity) QSold,
      MAX(SUM(t.Quantity))OVER(PARTITION BY t.prod_id) MaxQSold
    FROM Tb_Transactions t
    JOIN Tb_Supplier s ON s.supp_id=t.supp_id
    JOIN Tb_Product p ON t.prod_id=p.prod_id
    GROUP BY t.prod_id,p.name,s.city
  ) q
WHERE QSold=MaxQSold
```

Answer (score 0):

"*City where each product has been sold*" refers to the city of consumption, so you need to join transactions to consumers, sum the quantity by that city and the product. To arrive at "*the most*" we need a ranking so `dense_rank()` can ordered by the sum of quantity (descending) and a rank of 1 would equate to "the most sold" (note: equal 1st position is allowed by using `dense_rank()`).

```
SELECT
      d.city
    , p.name
    , d.sum_qty
FROM (
      SELECT
            c.city
          , SUM(t.quantity) sum_qty
          , t.prod_id
          , DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY c.city, t.prod_id ORDER BY SUM(t.quantity) DESC) rnk
      FROM Tb_Transactions t
      JOIN Tb_Consumer c ON t.con_id = c.con_id
) d
JOIN Tb_Product p ON d.Prod_ID = p.Prod_ID
WHERE d.rnk = 1
ORDER BY
      d.city
    , p.name
```

Joining the subquery result to product table reduces the rows involved in that join.

nb: using dense_rank also allows for "top n per" result, e.g. changing the where clause to `where rnk <= 5` would list top 5 selling products per city.